# Connection to MongoDB online using java not not working

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following code attempting to connect to mongodb

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
            "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.ytxrr.mongodb.net/testDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDatabase");
    
    MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("myTestCollection");
    
    Document document = new Document("Name","ALi").append("Age", 24).append("Country", "USA"); 
    
    collection.insertOne(document);

}
```

If I try to connect to localhost, it works fine. But if I try connecting online atlas server I get the following error

```
 INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01.ytxrr.mongodb.net:27017
 com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:541)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:429)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:269)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:253)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(SSLExtensions.java:90)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(CertificateRequest.java:818)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(CertificateRequest.java:922)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1460)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1368)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:878)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1240)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:426)
... 9 more
```

What is interesting is that I am getting the error on my desktop and not my laptop. I ran the same code on my laptop and it ran just fine and the Database and its corresponding collections and documents were created as it should be. I am trying ti understand what could cause this.

Comment: Set ip whitelist?

Comment: Its because of the java version. What is the java version u use? And mongo version?

Answer (score 0):

What is interesting is that the code worked on my laptop just fine, but failed on my desktop. Both of them were on JDK 14 (I don't think that was the issue). The localhost connection works just fine on both the Atlas connection failed on my desktop.

All said and done, I Upgraded JDK to 15 and had the same problem - works fine on my laptop, fails on my desktop!. Frustrated, I deleted the .m2 folder and rebuild the project. And Eureka!!! it works!!!

Really hate it when it happens but all is well.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in the TLS 1.3 implementation of various JDK versions. You can find a list of fix versions here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236039

Forcing TLS 1.2 is an alternative to upgrading the JDK.